# jenkins swarm plugin: Unable to connect to master. Connection refused

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am using jenkins swarm plugin to connect a slave node to a master node. However, it is giving `Connection Refused` error.

I am using docker swarm to deploy this on a multi node cluster. Right now I am testing with a single node setup only and here is my compose file for the setup:

```
version: '3.1'

    services:
      viz:
        image: manomarks/visualizer
        volumes:
          - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        ports:
          - "8090:8080"

      master:
        image: myproject-jenkins-master
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
          - "50000:50000"
        volumes:
          - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home

      nginx:
        image: myproject-jenkins-nginx
        ports:
          - "80:80"

      linuxagent:
        image: myproject-jenkins-linuxagent
```

And its being deployed using the `docker stack deploy` command so each of the above service gets its own internal load balancer.

Jenkins is served on web via nginx. But I've also kept port 8080 exposed for debugging. If I open my browser and hit either of `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8080`, I can access the jenkins web interface. On master, I have installed the jenkins `swarm` plugin. If I get inside the bash shell from my `linuxagent` container, which is intended to be a slave node, I can ping the other docker services but here is what happens when I try to run the `swarm-client-3.3.jar` file.

If I try to access jenkins, I can do so by accessing `http://myproject_master:8080`

```
root@d139902be5de:~# curl http://myproject_master:8080
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            root@d139902be5de:~#
```

Also, I can access the same via `http://myproject_nginx`

```
root@d139902be5de:~# curl http://myproject_nginx      
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->

</body></html>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            root@d139902be5de:~#
```

If I try to launch the jar file for swarm, I get this error:

```
root@d139902be5de:~# java -jar swarm-client-3.3.jar -username mandeep -password 12213 -master http://myproject_nginx      
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:44 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client main
INFO: Client.main invoked with: [-username mandeep -password 12213 -master http://myproject_nginx]
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:44 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Discovering Jenkins master
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:44 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Attempting to connect to http://myproject_nginx/ bc1be8e7-eaf0-47ff-8aeb-36f75d6ba081 with ID c84ce43b
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: d139902be5de-c84ce43b
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://myproject_nginx/]
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Agent discovery successful
  Agent address: myproject_nginx
  Agent port:    50000
  Identity:      86:5b:f3:77:84:92:21:87:95:4c:4b:0e:f7:4e:e5:1d
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:45 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to myproject_nginx:50000
Apr 09, 2017 5:52:55 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to myproject_nginx:50000 (retrying:2)
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to myproject_nginx:50000
  at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:243)
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.connect(Engine.java:500)
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.innerRun(Engine.java:364)
  at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:287)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:454)
  at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:446)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:648)
  at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:189)
  at org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.JnlpAgentEndpoint.open(JnlpAgentEndpoint.java:204)
  ... 3 more
```

Seems like the issue is that the slave expects master to be `myproject_nginx` and hence hits the port `50000` which fails because this service does not have port `50000` exposed. So for that purpose, I have exposed port `8080` and `50000` on the `myproject_master` service. But when I try that url, then I get a different error

```
root@d139902be5de:~# java -jar swarm-client-3.3.jar -username mandeep -password 12213 -master http://myproject_master:8080
Apr 09, 2017 5:57:01 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client main
INFO: Client.main invoked with: [-username mandeep -password 12213 -master http://myproject_master:8080]
Apr 09, 2017 5:57:01 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Discovering Jenkins master
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 09, 2017 5:57:01 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
SEVERE: IOexception occurred
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:286)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.open(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1361)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
  at hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient.discoverFromMasterUrl(SwarmClient.java:224)
  at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.run(Client.java:115)
  at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.main(Client.java:88)
```

This is where I am completely stuck and unable to understand how to fix the issue. Can there be a problem because the slave is running behind a load balancer ? Or is there anything fundamentally wrong in the architecture that I am trying to accomplish ? I want to be able to scale the `linuxagent` service dynamically so that each of the node behaves as a slave agent and just connects with the master node whenever it is launched. I read about the `swarm` plugin for jenkins and found that it can be used to achieve this kind of setup

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this? I'm facing same issue with similar setup

Comment: facing the same

Answer (score 0):

for me changing the order of parameters fixed it. 
Please move `-master` to beginning of swarm parameters as:

```
java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/swarm-client-3.4.jar -disableSslVerification -master
```

This should fix the following error which i was seeing:

```
Jul 25, 2017 6:26:23 PM hudson.plugins.swarm.Client run
INFO: Discovering Jenkins master
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for 
further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host 
name may not be null
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:68)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:107)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.setURI(HttpMethodBase.java:280)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:220)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod.<init>(GetMethod.java:89)
at hudson.plugins.swarm.SwarmClient.discoverFromMasterUrl(SwarmClient.java:220)
at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.run(Client.java:114)
at hudson.plugins.swarm.Client.main(Client.java:87)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up Inbound for TCP ports 443 and 50000 both.